# Perl add content to JSON data after processing

Tags: json, perl

I have a json file, which I am processing using perl `JSON` module.

Once I process it, I want to insert some content to in it.

Here is my input json file:

```
{
  "sequence" : [ 
  {
    "type" : "event",
    "attribute" : {     
      "contentText" : "Test Content",
      "contentNumber" : "11"
    }
  } 
  ],
  "current" : 0,
  "next" : 1
}
```

And below is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;

my $needed = 2;
my $filename = "test_file.json";

my $json_text = do {
            open(my $json_fh, "<:encoding(UTF-8)", $filename)
            or die("Can't open \$filename\": $!\n");
            local $/;
            <$json_fh>
    };

my $json = JSON->new;
my $data = $json->decode($json_text);

my $aref = $data->{sequence};

print Dumper($aref);

my $number;

for my $element (@$aref) {
    $number = $element->{attribute}->{contentNumber}."\n";
}

print "Number:$number\n";

my $total = $number + $needed;

foreach my $each_number ($number+1..$total){
    print $each_number."\n";
}

print Dumper $data;
```

So what I needed over here is fetch `contentNumber` from given json file and increment value by 1 till `$needed` is mentioned and form a new json file.

And finally it should form JSON file which should have content like below:
Where whatever `$needed` variable value is mentioned that many times the json should form the data including the initial data.

```
{
  "sequence" : [ 
  {
    "type" : "event",
    "attribute" : {     
      "contentText" : "Test Content",
      "contentNumber" : "11"
    }
  },
  {
    "type" : "event",
    "attribute" : {     
      "contentText" : "Test Content",
      "contentNumber" : "12"
    }
  },
  {
    "type" : "event",
    "attribute" : {     
      "contentText" : "Test Content",
      "contentNumber" : "13"
    }
  }
  ],
  "current" : 0,
  "next" : 1
}
```

I was thinking to push the data in `foreach` loop. But no clue how we can put it in data object which should give me an output with json format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the desired output it appears that you need the hashref which is in `sequence`'s array. Then you need to add `$needed` number of its copies to that array, with `contentNumber` incremented in each.  (I can't reconcile that with the shown code and I'll go with the desired output, which seems clear.)

Don't forget that the copies must be *deep* copies;<sup>†</sup> here I use `dclone` from [Storable](https://perldoc.perl.org/Storable.html) for that.

```
use Storable qw(dclone);

...

my $seq_href = dclone( $data->{sequence}[0] );

for (1..$needed) { 
    ++$seq_href->{attribute}{contentNumber};
    push @{$data->{sequence}}, dclone( $seq_href );
}

my $new_json_string = $json->encode($data);  # then write it to file
```

This produces the desired output JSON in my tests.

---

<sup>†</sup> A variable or data structure containing references cannot be copied into a new, independent one by merely assigning

```
my @copy = @ary;   # oups ... any references in there?
```

The problem is that when the elements that are references in `@ary` are copied into `@copy` then those elements in `@copy`, being the same references, point to same memory locations as the ones from `@ary`! So `@copy` and `@ary` are by no means independent -- they share data.

Sometimes that may be desired but if we need an independent copy, like in this problem, then we need to follow those references all the way and actually *copy the data* so that the copied structure indeed has its own data. And there are modules that do that of course.

Complex (nested) data structures by definition have references for elements and so we certainly can't get independent copies by one top-level assignment.

This is a very skinny description of a potentially sneaky and subtle bug.  I'd suggest to read up more on it. One resource that comes up is  an [*Effective Perler* article](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2010/03/make-deep-copies/).

Comment: Yes, I can see the data in ```Dumper($data)``` in my code. So how can I put this in ```.json``` file? Can I directly dump this in json file? Any suggestions?

Comment: @vinodk89 Ah, right, that (didn't notice in the question) --- convert back to JSON, using the same module, and then just write it out as a file.  I'll add this ...

Comment: @vinodk89 Added a line to produce a new JSON string from the altered `$data` (is that what you meant?), and a fat comment on the need for "deep" copy.

Comment: Yep @zdim. I have encoded the data which is in ```$data``` and written to a file. This works!! Thank you.